# Python extract sub string in between two pattern excluding floating number

Tags: python, regex, linux, string, substring

I am using python 2. I need to replace two sections in a string. For example something like below

```
str1 = "product,price=(decimals=4, value=7.505),quantity"
str2 = "product,(subporduct,(price=(decimals=4, value=7.05)),quantity"
str3 = "product,(subporduct,item=2, price=(decimals=4, value=7.05)),quantity"
```

I need the out put to be like this i.e. with price equals to the floating number

1. product,**price=7.505**,quantity
2. product,(subporduct,(**price=7.05**),quantity
3. product,(subporduct,item=2, **price=7.05**),quantity

I tried this but it leaves the last bracket, otherwise it is good enough for me.

```
print(re.sub("(?<=price=).+?(?<=value=)", "", str1))
```

I need the solution in python 2

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r'(price=)\([^()]*?value=([\d.]+)\)', r'\1\2', str1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(price=)\([^()]*?value=([\d.]+)\)', r'\1\2', str1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YM7K6n/1). *Details*:

- `(price=)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `price=` substring
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*?` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` as few as possible
- `value=` - a literal substring
- `([\d.]+)` - Group 2 (`\2`): one or more digit or `.` chars
- `\)` - a `)` char.

The replacement is the concatenation of Group 1 and 2 values.